# How to remove VSTS packages with cmdlets

Tags: azure-artifacts

I want to clear up the old VSTS Packages, and don't want to remove it individually. How can I do this with cmdlets?

Answer (score 0):

For CLI, you can just **unlist** VSTS packages but not delete them.

> Currently, NuGet.exe can only unlist packages; Team Services and TFS
>   interpret nuget.exe delete as an unlist operation to be consistent
>   with NuGet.org. To delete a package, you must use either the REST APIs
>   or the web interface.

More details, you can refer [unlist a package](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/unlist-delete#unlisting-a-package-using-nugetexe).

And deleting VSTS packages by REST API, you can refer[delete package](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/packaging/nuget#delete-package).